# ¿Cúal es la diferencia entre usar la etiqueta embed en vez de video o audio?

Tags: html, html5

Estoy empezando con `html5` y no me está quedando claro cuando usar `embed` en vez de video o audio. Mirando los codigo fuente veo que usan `embed`. ¿en embed el valor de `src` puede ser un video que tenga en una carpeta?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las etiquetas video y audio son específicas para dichas acciones (ver un vídeo o escuchar algún audio). Ahora bien, por un tema de compatibilidad y comodidad nos encontramos con la etiqueta embed, que permite realizar exactamente la misma acción pero es compatible con todos los navegadores existentes en el mercado.

Cabe destacar que la etiqueta embed accede a los archivos del servidor de audio/video y los muestra en tu página/sitio local. Las etiquetas audio/video no son compatibles con todos los navegadores.